# Sort a list of `List[Any]` by the first element using Scala

Tags: scala, sorting, casting

I want to sort my list by the first column in scala.

I have a list of list like this:

```
val a0 = List(0, "a0", 23)
val a1 = List(1, "a1", 231)
val a2 = List(2, "a2", 1)
val a3 = List(3, "a3", 80)
val a4 = List(4, "a4", 33)
val a5 = List(5, "a5", 23)
val a6 = List(6, "a6", 2)
val list1 = List(a0, a6, a2, a3, a1, a5, a4)
```

I want to sort it by the first column, so the expected output is:

```
List(  
  List(0, a0, 23),
  List(1, a1, 231),
  List(2, a2, 1),
  List(3, a3, 80),
  List(4, a4, 33),
  List(5, a5, 23),
  List(6, a6, 2)
)
```

I tried

```
list1.sortBy(list => list(0))
```

but it produces

> error: No implicit Ordering defined for Any

How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide the output format

Comment: Sorry, I have already put it on.

Comment: To generate the input code: `for ((k,j) <- List(23, 231, 1, 80, 33, 23, 2).zipWithIndex) println(s"""val a$j = List($j, "a$j", $k)"""); println(List(0,6,2,3,1,5,4).map("a" + _).mkString("val list1 = List(", ", ", ")"))` ; Please don't post code as image.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. And I want to use the list1 to produces result, can you get the results with sorted,sortBy or sortWith? Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your input again:

```
val a0 = List(0, "a0", 23)
val a1 = List(1, "a1", 231)
val a2 = List(2, "a2", 1)
val a3 = List(3, "a3", 80)
val a4 = List(4, "a4", 33)
val a5 = List(5, "a5", 23)
val a6 = List(6, "a6", 2)
val list1 = List(a0, a6, a2, a3, a1, a5, a4)
```

Here is how you sort it:

```
val list2 = list1.sortBy(_(0).asInstanceOf[Int])
```

The `(0)` gets the first entry, the `asInstanceOf[Int]` casts it to integer. The `_` is the placeholder for the list, it's an abbreviation for `(list: List[Any]) => list(0).asInstanceOf[Int]`.

If you print the result

```
list2 foreach println
```

you get

```
List(0, a0, 23)
List(1, a1, 231)
List(2, a2, 1)
List(3, a3, 80)
List(4, a4, 33)
List(5, a5, 23)
List(6, a6, 2)
```

Comment: Nice one @Andrey.

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar generating the input was more "interesting" than the question itself, but I decided that neither the `_`, nor the `asInstanceOf`-parts are particularly obvious for an average python user, for example...

Comment: You solved my problem perfectly.Thank you very much!